# checkboxradio inside popup error when cloned

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a complex offline web app that generate dynamic pages by cloning a master page.
On this page, I have a popup with radio buttons on it. When I click on those radio, I get the "cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization" error.

I reduced my code to this test case :
http://jsbin.com/lanulu/1/

If you go to page 2 (the master page) or page 3 (the cloned page), and click the "click here button, you can click on the radio or the checkbox. The checkbox work well and generate no error. But the radio generate the error.

Il you remove the code that clone the page and go to page2, everything work fine.

I had a lot of those problems in the past with cloned pages, but I always resolved it by making all id's unique. But this time it's not enough…

Any clue ?

Thanks

html :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul>
     <li> <a href="#page2">Page2</a>
      <li><a href="#page3">Page3</a>
      </ul> 
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-content">
      <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
      <a data-role="button" class="foo">Click here</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popup_cs"  class="popup_cs">
        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="radio" name="cs" id="cs-box" class="box" value="box">
                <label for="cs-box">foo</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cs" id="cs-tg" class="tg" value="tg">
                <label for="cs-tg">bar</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
  $("#page2")
     .clone()
     .appendTo("body")
     .attr("id","page3")
     .attr("data-url","page3");
  $("#page3 h1").text("Page 3");
  $("#page3 .popup_cs").attr("id", "popup_cs2");
  $("#page2 .popup_cs label").attr("for", function(i, val) { return val + "-3";});
  $("#page3 .popup_cs input").attr("id", function(i, val) { return val + "-3";});
});


$(document).on("click", ".foo", function() {
    var popup = $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).find(".popup_cs");
    popup.popup("open", {positionTo: $(this)});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two *radio buttons* in DOM with same `name`, which means they are connected to each others. When you select/check one, jQM deselect other one and then calls `.checkboxradio("refresh")`. When *refresh* method is called on an element which isn't *created* or *initialized*, you get an error:

> cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

The solution is to change `name` attribute of cloned *radio button* as well as *checkbox*. Each group should have a unique `name` since all elements are in DOM at the same time.

```
$("#page3 .popup_cs input")
    .attr({
    id: function (i, val) {
        return val + "-3";
    },
    name: function (i, val) {
        return val + "-3";
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n4adctpd/)**

Comment: I spent 3 hours on this without founding it, and it was soooo simple !! Thank you very much Omar !!

Comment: @Matthieu you're welcome :) if you still want both radio buttons to have the same `name`, just intialize the cloned one manually by calling `.checkboxradio()`.